# How do I configure Jenkins so it will create failed builds instead of unstable builds?

Tags: jenkins, build

I’m using the Jenkins WAR on Tomcat 6 (Java 7).  How do I configure Jenkins so that it will no longer create unstable builds but simply failed builds?  I’ve created a freestanding job that uses the Gradle plugin.  The Gradle options are configured like so:

```
Use Gradle wrapper (checked)
Switches = “-Penv=qa”
Tasks = “clean build”
Root Build script = “./myproject/“
```

There is a post build step with the following commands

```
cd myproject
cp ./build/libs/myproject.war /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Text-finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) to search the build log and fail the build if it's unstable.